# Replace word wrap

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use the javascript replace function to only wrap around one instance? For example, if I had

```
var string = '**blah*';
string = string.replace('*', 'text').replace('*', 'word');
```

This would make the string 'textwordblah', but is there a way to make it 'text*blahword'?

Comment: your example is ambiguous. even if someone answer. it will hardly work with your real data.

Comment: @MasterPlato can you please tell the pattern you are looking for

Comment: what pattern? I an just asking if you can take a separate `"*"`, so it is only by itself. `"**"` would not be taken but `"*a*"` would.

Comment: @MasterPtato what will happen if it is `***blah*`

Comment: That still wont work except for the ending `*`, because the first 3 aren't separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```
<(?!\*)
```